# How to use Bootstrap Div in loop ..?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, shopify, liquid

I have tried a lot to bring my blog to post 3 in a row using bootstrap in Shopify. But I'm unable do that because of for loop.

Now only one blog post is coming in one row [blog url](https://www.sprintshopping.com/blogs/fashion). I want to display 3 blogs in a row.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 main-col">
   <div class="content-blog">
    <ul class="list-blog" style="list-style: none;">
     {% for article in blog.articles %}
     <li class="myownstyleclass" style=" border: 2px solid #D3D3D3; padding-left:15px;"> 
       <h3><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3></li>
     {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried with one more logic:

```
<ul class="list-blog" style="list-style: none;">
{% for article in blog.articles %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 main-col">
   <div class="content-blog">
     <li class="myownstyleclass" style=" border: 2px solid #D3D3D3; padding-left:15px;"> 
      <h3><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3></li>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Nothing is helping. Any help? I am very new to this.

Comment: In your rendered code over at `view-source:https://www.sprintshopping.com/blogs/fashion`, I only see the myownstyleclass class repeated once after each "content-blog" class -- indicating that your `{% for article in blog.articles %}` contain a data set with just one row (not three rows or more as you seem to be expecting).
I am referring to these tags:
`<div class="content-blog"><li class="myownstyleclass" ... >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="list-blog" style="list-style: none;">
   <div class="row">
     {% for article in blog.articles %}
    <div class="col-xs-4 main-col">
       <div class="content-blog">
 <li class="myownstyleclass" style=" border: 2px solid #D3D3D3; padding-left:15px;"> 
   <h3><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3></li>

          </div>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
        </div>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for article in blog.articles %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       <h3><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
    </div>      
    {% endfor %}   
  </div>
</div>
```

See [URL](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#quick-start-example) for more information on GRID